# How can i customize the highlighted error in vim by file .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I want to make highlighted errors underline instead of background red as default with my ~/.vimrc. The below is an image from ALE plugin(of course I have that plugin but the error is always with background red) and that is what I'd like to have.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look up ALE's default highlighting configuration at [:help ale-highlights](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/blob/cae40e1c347064bd3ab5eb4c04e9e357d3d82105/doc/ale.txt#L1918). There, you'll see that the `ALEError` highlight group is linked to `SpellBad`, which is a definition that ships with Vim: [`:help hl-SpellBad`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-SpellBad).

Vim's default for a color terminal is indeed a red background (but a chosen *colorscheme* may change that). You can influence that by either switching to a different colorscheme, or by customizing it, like this (placed in your `~/.vimrc` after any `:colorscheme` command):

```
:hi SpellBad cterm=underline ctermfg=red ctermbg=NONE
```

Note that GVIM uses the `undercurl` attribute, but that isn't available in terminals, so `underline` is used (and even that may or may not be available for your terminal).

Comment: so the command in .vimrc should be 'autocmd hi SpellBad cterm=underline ctermfg=red ctermbg=NONE' because I want it to run from the beginning but my .vimrc will throw error no such group or event.

Comment: Your `:autocmd` is missing the event and pattern; you probably meant `:autocmd VimEnter * hi SpellBad ...`. Actually, there's a `ColorScheme` event just for that, but as long as you don't switch colorschemes during the editing session, none of that should be needed; just put the `:hi` command after any `:colorscheme` command, as mentioned.

Comment: For what it's worth, this worked for me but :help ale-highlights didn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

`ALEError` handles highlighting rule for the errored tokens which may just be a single character depending upon your linter.

If you'd rather have the entire line underlined:

```
:highlight link ALEErrorLine SpellBad
```

Comment: iterm2 users, you can change underline color in `Profiles -> color -> Underline color`